# iOS6 editting a uitextfield when touch event ocurred

Tags: ios, uitextfield, gesture, uitextfielddelegate

I have tableviewcell that is subclassing a uitextfield, i want to drag the cell a certain position and when relesed the cursor and keyboard for editing must appear, however when using the method "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" i have to tap the cell for start editing, otherwise the cell wont do anything. I'd really appreciate any suggestions. Thx.

Comment: You must not call `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`. That will be called for you when appropriate. Are you calling `becomeFirstResponder` on the text field?

Comment: where do i exactly make the calling becomeFirstResponder?

Comment: In whatever code you have that indicates the text field should start editing. Perhaps the code that handles the end of the dragging.

Comment: Thanks a lot rmaddy, it worked!!!